# Android webview code not displaying web page

Tags: android, android-layout

Am triggering below `WebUrlActivity.class` once app is launched.  am unable to display web page once the below `class` is triggered from the home screen(home screen code I haven't put here). It comes up as white screen. Can you please advise.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

```
package xx.xxxxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebUrlActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private final String URL = "xyz.com/admin";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_url);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setTitle("xyz");
        setTitleColor(Color.BLACK);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                view.loadUrl(request.toString());
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, WebUrlActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use url with https like this https://xyz.xyz/

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be in an infinite loop of loading the url in "shouldOverrideUrlLoading". Try removing that whole "setwebviewclient" part. Also, your URL doesn't lead with "HTTP://" or anything like that, so the webview might not recognize your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the URL with `http://` or `https://`
like http://www.google.com